# Error arising during executing command "npx create-react-app my-app"

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

When I run the command "npx create-react-app my-app"  in the terminal, it throws the following error:
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall lstat

npm ERR! path C:\Users\ COMMUNICATION\AppData\Roaming\npm

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\COMMUNICATION\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-24T15_57_55_463Z-debug-0.log

I am new to React and i am unable to configure the problem.
Anyone please help me to configure the above error.